# Hibernate flush optimization using `hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer`

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am trying to use the hibernate feature that enhances the flush performance without making code changes. I came across the option **hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer**.
I made the following changes.

1) enabled the property hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer to true.
*Build failed with error 'Cannot apply class transformer without LoadTimeWeaver specified'*

2) I added 
    **context:load-time-weaver** to the context files.
*Build failed with the following error :
Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring’s agent: -javaagent:spring-agent.jar*

3) I added the following to the maven-surefire-plugin
    **javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-
    agent/2.5.6.SEC03/spring-agent-2.5.6.SEC03.jar**

the build is successful now.

We have an interceptor that tracks the number of entities being flushed in a transaction.
After I did the above changes, I was expecting that number to come down significantly, but, they did not.

My question is:

1. Are the above changes correct/enough for getting the 'entity flush optimization'?
2. How to verify that the application is indeed using the optimization?

**Edit:**

After debugging, I found the following.
There is a time when our DO class is submitted for transformation, but, the logic that figures out whether a given class is supposed to be transformed is not handling the class names correctly (in my case), because of that, the DO class goes without being transformed. 
Is there a way I can pass my logic instead ?

the relevant code is below.
The `return copyEntities.contains( className );` is coming out false for the following inputs.
copyEntities contains list of strings `"com.x.y.abcDO", "com.x.y.asxDO"` where are the className is `"com.x.y.abcDO_$$_jvsteb8_48"`

```
public InterceptFieldClassFileTransformer(List<String> entities) {
        final List<String> copyEntities = new ArrayList<String>( entities.size() );
        copyEntities.addAll( entities );
        classTransformer = Environment.getBytecodeProvider().getTransformer(
                //TODO change it to a static class to make it faster?
                new ClassFilter() {
                    public boolean shouldInstrumentClass(String clas    sName) {
                        return copyEntities.contains( className );
                    }
                },
                //TODO change it to a static class to make it faster?
                new FieldFilter() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldInstrumentField(String clas    sName, String fieldName) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldTransformFieldAccess(
                        String transformingClassName, String fieldOwnerClassName, String fieldName
                ) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
    );
}
```

**edited on June 15th**

I updated my project to use Spring 4.0.5.RELEASE and hibernate to 4.3.5.Final
I started using `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider`
and
`org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver`
and
`hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer=true`

with these changes, I am debugging the flush behavior. I have a question in this code block .

```
private boolean isUnequivocallyNonDirty(Object entity) {

    if(entity instanceof SelfDirtinessTracker)
        return ((SelfDirtinessTracker) entity).$$_hibernate_hasDirtyAttributes();

    final CustomEntityDirtinessStrategy customEntityDirtinessStrategy =
            persistenceContext.getSession().getFactory().getCustomEntityDirtinessStrategy();
    if ( customEntityDirtinessStrategy.canDirtyCheck( entity, getPersister(), (Session) persistenceContext.getSession() ) ) {
        return ! customEntityDirtinessStrategy.isDirty( entity, getPersister(), (Session) persistenceContext.getSession() );
    }

    if ( getPersister().hasMutableProperties() ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( getPersister().getInstrumentationMetadata().isInstrumented() ) {
        // the entity must be instrumented (otherwise we cant check dirty flag) and the dirty flag is false
        return ! getPersister().getInstrumentationMetadata().extractInterceptor( entity ).isDirty();
    }

    return false;
}
```

In my case, the flow is returning false because of `persister saying yes for hasMutableProperties`. I think the interceptor did not have a chance to answer at all.
Is it not that the bytecode transformer cause an interceptor here? Or the bytecode transform should make the entity a `SelfDirtinessTracker`?

Can anyone explain, what is the behavior I should expect here from the bytecode transformation here.